# Difference between CallExpression and MemberExpression

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the difference? I looked at the ECMAScript specification, but did not understand. The real code examples that would help much.

If you can explain every line here it would be nice

```
MemberExpression : 
 PrimaryExpression 
 FunctionExpression
 MemberExpression [ Expression ] 
 MemberExpression . IdentifierName 

CallExpression : 
 MemberExpression Arguments
 CallExpression Arguments 
 CallExpression [ Expression ] 
 CallExpression . IdentifierName
```

For example

```
console.log - MemberExpression: MemberExpression . IdentifierName
console.log("hi") - CallExpression : MemberExpression Arguments
```

What is will be equal

```
CallExpression : CallExpression . IdentifierName
CallExpression [ Expression ]
CallExpression : CallExpression Arguments
```

Link for ES http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant parts here are

```
NewExpression:
    MemberExpression
    new NewExpression
LeftHandSideExpression:
    NewExpression
    CallExpression
```

which distinguishes the three major left hand side expressions:

- constructor calls
- function/method calls
- primary expressions

And all of them with member accesses in the right places. As such, the difference between the productions you listed is just that a `CallExpression` always contains a call - and may therefore not be part of the expression after a  `new`operator.

Comment: Explain to me the difference between `MemberExpression . IdentifierName` and `CallExpression . IdentifierName`

Comment: I readed it! But can you give me example for `CallExpression . IdentifierName` or  `CallExpression Arguments`  I don't imagine this, how it will be (`MemberExpression . IdentifierName` or `MemberExpression Arguments` I do imagine it).

Comment: @MaximPro `member().callProperty` and `member()()` (vs `member.memberProperty` and `member()`).

Comment: Interesting. `MemberExpression Arguments` - Its `CallExpression` Right?

Comment: Yes, that's what your question says: `CallExpression : 
 MemberExpression Arguments`

Answer (score 17):

- `func()` is a `CallExpression`
- `thing.func` is a `MemberExpression`

  - `thing` is the `object` of the `MemberExpression`
  - `func` is the `property` of the `MemberExpression`
- `thing.func()` is a `MemberExpression` within a `CallExpression`

  - `thing.func` is the `callee` of the `CallExpression`

Source: [astexplorer.net](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/8b16411cac74187db797974c633bc22f/dae9120a20ec57681cfd9d17dd4bae1a900361a5).

Comment: Can you give me explanations with this http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2 (about every line MemberExpression and CallExpression)
Especially **MemberExpression [ Expression ]** and **CallExpression [ Expression ]** or **MemberExpression . Expression** and **CallExpression . Expression**

Comment: They're defining the grammar of various `Expressions` by enumerating what other expressions they can encompass. If you want to learn what they _all_ mean, refer to the AST specification of a JavaScript parser such as [babylon](https://github.com/babel/babylon/blob/master/ast/spec.md).