# Difference between VariableDeclaration and VariableDeclarationNoIn

Tags: ecmascript-6

In ECMA document we have

> The `VariableDeclarationListNoIn`, `VariableDeclarationNoIn` and
>   `InitialiserNoIn` productions are evaluated in the same manner as the
>   `VariableDeclarationList`, `VariableDeclaration` and `Initialiser`
>   productions except that the contained `VariableDeclarationListNoIn`,
>   `VariableDeclarationNoIn`, `InitialiserNoIn` and `AssignmentExpressionNoIn`
>   are evaluated instead of the contained `VariableDeclarationList`,
>   `VariableDeclaration`, `Initialiser` and `AssignmentExpression`,
>   respectively.

But what does mean VariableDeclaration**NoIn**?

Comment: I can only find the quoted text in the ES5 spec. Why is this tagged ES6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a variable declaration whose intialiser must not contain the `in` operator. Consider

```
var example = propertyName in object;
```

which is not a valid `VariableDeclarationListNoIn`. These kinds of productions are used in the [`for` loop syntax](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6) and prevent any ambiguity in things like

```
for (var example = propertyName in object; example; example = !example) … // invalid
```

Comment: Can you look another my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972903/difference-between-callexpression-and-memberexpression